# Car feels like it’s going to stall at lower speeds

Tags: stall

Today car started feeling like it’ll stall at lower speeds. Almost like it’s shuddering. It also idles at about 800 RPM instead of the usual 1000. I looked it up and seems most likely to do with an air inlet valve (correct me if I’m wrong).

I’m currently not at home and am due to go back tomorrow, meaning I need to drive the car for about 1hr 40mins, 1hr 30 of which is on the motorway and shouldn’t involve slowing down except once at a roundabout. Would this be an issue to drive or is it ok? I’ll compensate for the lack of RPM by over revving at slower speeds. Will also take car to garage the next day. So would it be safe to drive? No warning lights have come on as of yet. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've taken the part out of the question about "cost" as that would make the question off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think if you don't have warning lights, you can compensate for the lower RPMs, and the engine isn't running different otherwise, you shouldn't have any issues. It's when you start seeing a CEL or the engine is running rough or something else is quite noticeably different you'd need to be worried about getting it home. Keep a close eye on things and be cognizant of things if they change.

Comment: Will do! Thank you, just need to complete this one journey then can get it to a garage. I’ll keep an eye on it when driving. Haven’t unlocked comments yet.